# Outlook: Autoremove unused addresses from autocomplete

Tags: microsoft-outlook, autocomplete

I want to prevent selecting the incorrect email address when composing messages.

Microsoft Outlook's autocomplete feature aids me in achieving this goal by preventing typos that might occur if I had to manually type email addresses each time. However, it also poses a challenge by suggesting email addresses of unintended recipients.

If Microsoft Outlook could automatically remove email addresses from the autocomplete list after a certain period of inactivity, such as three months, it would significantly reduce the likelihood of inaccurate suggestions.

Is there a method to implement this cleanup process, either through an automatic feature or by utilizing a script?

Comment: Clear Outlook Autocomplete using this Microsoft Article:    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/contacts/information-about-the-outlook-autocomplete-list

Comment: @John I'm not sure I understand: Where do I enter the 3 months? I obviously do not want to clear everything - only the entries not used for 3 months.

Comment: If you need to remove individual items, select the item, push the down arrow to select the item, and delete the item (delete key). These are the only two deletion methods I know of.

Comment: Agree with John, we can only delete individual addresses or entire list of AutoComplete list.